# A Game Between a Panda and a Polar Bear

Tags: game-theory

I've been working on some problems related to Bayesian games, and I reached
this dynamic game that I have been having some problems with. Consider a game
where a polar bear and panda bear are choosing to fight or not fight. The polar
bear knows whether he is soft or tough, but the panda knows that the polar
bear is soft or tough with probabilities $\frac{1}{7}$ and $\frac{6}{7}$
respectively. The Polar Bear has the choice to stay on the ice ($I$) or go
to land ($L$). The Panda Bear observes this action, but does not observe
whether the Polar Bear is soft or tough. The panda can choose to fight the
Polar Bear ($Fi$) or ignore it by eating bamboo ($B$). If the Panda chooses to
fight, the Panda gets a payoff of $-3$ if the Polar Bear is tough and $1$ if
the Polar Bear is soft. If the Panda stays eating bamboo, the panda will earn
$0$. If the Polar Bear is soft, the Polar Bear obtains a payoff of $-2$ in the
case that the Panda fights and $1$ if the Panda stays eating bamboo. If the
Polar Bear is tough, the Polar Bear earns a payoff of $0$ if the Panda Fights
and $1$ if the Panda stays eating bamboo. Moreover, the Polar Bear must face
a cost $c_{PB} > 0$ if the Polar Bear goes on land ($L$).

I'm interested in figuring out the conditions on $c_{PB}$ in order to
guarantee the existence of a "separating" Perfect Bayesian Equilibrium. Any
suggestions on how to go about this kind of problem?

Comment: Apart from the cost $c_{PB}^{}$, what is the impact of the ice/land choice? Does the polar bear staying on ice prevent any fight?

Comment: This sounds like a relabeling of the Beer-Quiche game. Obviously the payoffs are a little different, but all of the analysis will carry through as long as they are ordinally equivalent. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3kI3mLC8t0) is a nice demo on finding BNE in this context (I think the set of PBE will equal the set of BNE (Bayes-Nash Equilibrium) in this context, but am not entirely sure). If you disagree that this game is ordinally equivalent to Beer-Quiche, please explain the critical differences. Or explain your particular interest in PBE, as opposed to BNE.